# For loop inside Jinja2 template with CSV

Tags: python, csv, jinja2

I am trying to build an output based on a jinja2 template using a CSV as input. How could I use the for loop inside the template instead of inside the python code to render the output?

This is the code I have been working on. The code works fine without the for loop in the template. When the for loop is added to the template the output contains the same vlan information duplicated.

Is there any way to include the for-loop in the template, so that the iteration is performed in at the template level?

```
import csv
from jinja2 import Template

source_file = "VLAN.csv"
vlan_template_file = "vlan.j2"
vlan_configs = ""

with open(vlan_template_file) as tf:
    vlan_template = Template(tf.read(), keep_trailing_newline=True)

with open(source_file) as sf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(sf)
    for row in reader:
        vlan_config = vlan_template.render(row)    
        vlan_configs += vlan_config +"!\n"
print(vlan_configs)
```

`

The vlan_configs output provides the vlan details twice.

CSV file format:

```
vlan_id,vlan_name
10,VLAN_10
11,VLAN_11
12,VLAN_12
```

jinja2 template:

```
{% for vlan_id in row %}
vlan {{vlan_id}}
name {{vlan_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Probably you don't need the `for row in reader:` line in your Python code. That line is executing the code below once per `row`. But the template `for` is also executing once per `row`. BTW, can you edit your code so that it is well indented? Thanks!

Comment: Can you pass `reader` to the jinja2 template as `vlan_template.render(reader)`?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback rturrado. When I change the code to `vlan_template.render(reader)`, Im getting the following error: `line 1086, in render
    vars = dict(*args, **kwargs)`
`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required`

Comment: That's right. If you want the for loop in the template, you will need to pass the reader variable, which is a dictionary. So youl'll have to modify the template code accordingly. E.g. `for vlan_id in reader` and `name {{reader[vlan_id]}}` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Python code to:

```
with open(source_file) as sf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(sf)
    vlan_config = vlan_template.render(csv=reader)
    vlan_configs += vlan_config + "!\n"
print(vlan_configs)
```

And your jinja template to:

```
{% for row in csv %}
vlan {{row["vlan_id"]}}
name {{row["vlan_name"]}}
{% endfor %}
```

Explanation:

- From your Python code you just send the `DictReader` to the jinja template. So you only do one loop in the jinja template and not in the Python code.
- `DictReader` is a list of dictionaries.
- The jinja template walks each row in the `DictReader`. Each row is a dict. You access the values of each row with `row["vlan_id"]` and `row["vlan_name"]`.

Comment: Thanks rturrado. The code works as expected.

Comment: Beautiful! Nice to hear.